# How can I order my results by a secondary index or column in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, sql-order-by

I am looking to build a table that will allow me to filter rows by timestamp and region. Here is what I have below:

```
  CREATE TABLE event_start(  
        user_id text,  
        ts timestamp,  
        region text,  
        PRIMARY KEY(ts, region)  
    )  
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(region DESC);
```

When I try and select and order the results by region, I run into "ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN."
I think I understand the error message, but I am having trouble conceiving of a solution. Would this be related to the primary key vs the clustering key?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement, maybe switching the partition and cluster keys could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly query on this table by clustering column.
You must have to provide Partition key(ts).

You can query without partition key – only by clustering columns:
BUT it causes Cassandra to scan ALL partitions!!!!
For this you need to append **ALLOW FILTERING** in your query.

**Below is the Querying Order:**

1. First – must provide a partition key
2. Clustering column(s) can follow after
3. it Can perform either equality(=) or range queries on clustering columns
4. All equality comparison must come before inequality comparison
5. Range searches are a binary search followed by a linear read

You can revert your key columns to satisfy your query:

```
CREATE TABLE event_start(  
      user_id text,  
      ts timestamp,  
      region text,  
      PRIMARY KEY(region, ts)  
  );
```

Comment: Thank you, I must have had the order a bit off. I am able to create the table now with the ORDER BY.